# Could Rails 3.0's "gem install rails" or "bundle install" install a sqlite3.dll as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.0 installation on Windows was almost seamless, except it'd still just say sqlite3.dll is missing and I think the solution is to find it and then put into one of your path such as c:\ruby192\bin or c:\windows ?

Supposedly, can `gem install` or `bundle install` actually put it somewhere that is usable?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite itself is a third-party library and it cannot be packaged within driver. As an example: should RubyGems also install MySQL when installing `ruby-mysql`? The answer is, no.

Comment: MySQL is so big... compared to SQLite3... which is extremely small.  I think we can cut the line at "third party", but then some other third party package, we can still gem install, can't we?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how big it is. Don't forget, Ruby is available on a couple of platforms. Do you really want to deliver with `gem install` binaries for Windows, Linux and MacOSX? Or ship three different gems for each platform? This is not a RubyGems way.